# Facebook PHP SDK - How to Handle The Situation When A Non-User of Your App clicks on an App Notification They Have Been Sent By A Friend?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a facebook app that a user can send an app request to friends. The notification doesn't do anything special, it is simply a notification to say their friend has used the app and they should try it too etc.

What happens is, the app user's friend receives a notification, it appears on their screen, but when they click the notification they are taken to a screen containing the canvas with the facebook header at the top.

The problem is, my app tab is fan-gated so all they see is an image prompting them to click the like button.... and there is no like button. Only an image and the facebook header.

So, to summarise, how to direct users who receive app notifications from friends to the actual app tab and not the canvas page?

I can provide code but I don't think it's necessary for this question.

I've read this documentation on Facebook but it hasn't made me any wiser :/
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/#requests

Any help and pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this check in Javascript:

```
// Check if address was from a apprequest
if(window.top.location.search.indexOf('request_ids')) {
    // Redirect to your tab
    window.top.location = 'http://www.facebook.com/BMW?sk=app_167533506634184';
}
```